# Salesforce Chatter Group Deactivated

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups

We have a Salesforce Chatter group that was archived. (We already activated it again.)

- It had a post on it on 2/12/2024, so it should *not* have been auto-archived.
- I don't see anything in the setup audit trail (and I'm guessing it doesn't get logged there anyway),

But is there somewhere I can see who/how it got deactivated?

*It's a small company, and no one says they did it and I'm curious if there's a ghost in the machine.*

Comment: You can try querying on 'CollaborationGroup' which represents a Chatter group. (SELECT LastFeedModifiedDate,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,LastReferencedDate FROM CollaborationGroup)